# What data/service is where?

Tags: metadata, soa, esb

What management tools (open source or otherwise) are there to track the location of data, the services that deliver/use that data and the services themselves. If you believe the snake oil a combination of DB, ESB and SOA will deliver anything anywhere, but how do you know what's where. BTW I'm not interested at the WSDL level, I'm thinking of a tool that the users/BA community would populate and use.

A combination of SOA and Database is now the bedrock of most applications, however what used to be called Data Dictionaries, and would now be Service Catalogues? or MetaData repositories still seem to live in purely DataCentric world.

Answer (score 0):

Software AG's [CentraSite](http://www.centrasite.org).

Disclosure: I work for Software AG :)

Answer (score 0):

There are public and Enterprise **service repositories** for this.